# Why can't I attach properties to Window in TypeScript files that export?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

This compiles fine:

```
interface Window {
    foo:boolean;
}

window.foo = true;
```

But the moment I add this onto the bottom...

```
export class Bar {}
```

...I get this error `Error TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Window'.`

What's the explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an exported object, your file is a *module* and gets its own scope, meaning that your declaration of `Window` declares a new type (namespaced inside your module) rather than contributing to the global interface `Window`.

To change things in the global scope, use the `declare global` syntax:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    foo:boolean;
  }
}
```